# Render partial for only certain views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey I have a partial for a navigation bar in my rails project in my `shared` folder. I want it to load the nav bar for everything except any of my views associated with my `score` object. How can I write that condition out in the `application.html.erb` file?

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <%= render 'shared/navigation' if @some_condition %>
        <%= yield %>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a current_page? helper in rails.

```
<% if current_page?(controller: 'score' action: 'show') %>
  <!-- render somthing -->
<% else %>
  <%= render 'shared/navigation' if @some_condition %>
  <%= yield %>
<% end %>
```

Link to information http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F